# Double requests when scraping images, videos

Tags: python, web-scraping

When you scrape media for example images from Instagram by first scrolling through let's say an influencer's page to get the image links, then sending download requests to the links. Will Instagram recognize this as double requests every time since in order for the images or image links to first display on the site I would assume (I may be wrong here) that the scraper has to have requested the displayed images once before sending download requests by url? Wouldn't this easily be recognized by Instagram autobot?

I would like to minimize the chance of Instagram detection which would lead to sending out CATPCHAS to the particular user (in this case that would be me using the scraper that includes static proxy, cookies and sessions) and possibly ban the user and the IP address used; or Instagram sending out CATPCHAS to all requests associated with the influencer's posts that are not the first few posts, and since you need to be a logged in user and scroll down to a certain point in order to access the images/videos (if this is the case I think using rotational proxies would solve the problem).

In a more general sense, I would like to scrape social media with real user emulations  with some individual usernames that will always be logged in with certain proxies and so on. If without using rotational proxies later on to download the media files, what would the best pratices be?

Comment: What is your question exactly? You have some ideas on hand, have you tested any of them? From your first paragraph, when a normal user loads instagram, a series of image/videos have already been loaded. This equals to just 1 request. The scrolling part of it does not count as a request.

Comment: So say you go through each post and if there're multiple images/videos within a post like on Instagram, everytime you click on a post does this equal to one request as well?

Comment: Yes, it's considered another request if you click from the user profile and a single page is launched with just that particular image/videos. Anyhow, when you download the image/video, you will need to use something like request.get(img_url) so you will be requesting for every download.

Comment: Thanks how about if you click on a post and view it as displayed by Javascript, will every right arrow click be counted as one request for example if a post contains 5 images/videos, will it go towards 1 request or 5?

Comment: clicks and requests are two different things. imagine if you enter a link on your browser and hit enter, that is a request because you are sending the request command to retrieve the webpage. whereas clicks are just registered as inputs on the webpage. certain websites are designed to register clicks on the webpage to determine if you are a bot or not. For example, if you click at the same spot too many times or click at locations without any interactive buttons, etc, then you are most likely a bot. Not having any clicks at all is also weird. Therefore sometimes we induce random clicks too.